# How to mock weld-se StartMain args in Arquillian

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

I am working on a project that needs to use org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain args in a method. So, how can I mock the StartMain args to test the method using Arquillian? Thank you very much.

For example, given a method like this:

```
@Inject @Parameters
List<String> args;

public String foo() {
    return args[0];
}
```

how would you test it?